# Regex to find numbers and parenthesize them in a passage

Tags: c#, regex

given the passage below:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis
>   2. Varius enim in tempor. Vivamus vel rutrum lacus. Donec quis
>   ullamcorper purus. Nullam blandit tincidunt mattis. Nunc imperdiet
>   nunc vel dolor 3 - dignissim semper. Cras blandit laoreet nisl sit
>   amet faucibus. Sed porta, nisl ut molestie ultrices, libero metus
>   scelerisque nibh, non imperdiet lectus sapien a lorem. Sed elementum
>   10 adipiscing erat, eget consectetur massa ultrices eget. Integer leo
>   est, faucibus eu 24interdum eget, auctor bibendum ligula. Quisque
>   luctus lectus vitae leo semper gravida. Cras et pulvinar leo. Nulla
>   tristique98 ipsum ac urna luctus molestie.

what regex should I use to find the numerals within it and put parenthesis around them.

Comment: Regex would look something like `gr/\d+/[$1]/`, but I haven't been using them in c#, so I can't tell you exact solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        var data = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis 2. Varius enim in tempor. Vivamus vel rutrum lacus. Donec quis ullamcorper purus. Nullam blandit tincidunt mattis. Nunc imperdiet nunc vel dolor 3 - dignissim semper. Cras blandit laoreet nisl sit amet faucibus. Sed porta, nisl ut molestie ultrices, libero metus scelerisque nibh, non imperdiet lectus sapien a lorem. Sed elementum 10 adipiscing erat, eget consectetur massa ultrices eget. Integer leo est, faucibus eu 24interdum eget, auctor bibendum ligula. Quisque luctus lectus vitae leo semper gravida. Cras et pulvinar leo. Nulla tristique98 ipsum ac urna luctus molestie.";
        var newData = Regex.Replace(data, @"(\d+)", "($1)");
        Console.WriteLine(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
string strRegex = @"(?<num>\d+)";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"You text with 4 numbers";
string strReplace = @"""${num}""";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```